# Ruby on Rails question - where is the first point in rails code that a request hits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails question - where is the first point in rails code that a request hits?

(I can then add some logging code there as I want to measure some response times)

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware) on Rack Middleware that will give you exactly that.  Rack is the first place that a Rails 2.3+ app has requests hit and it handles the round trip of the request.